# How to send data from MySQL to index.html using Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

So I studied how to send data from MySQL to localhost:3000/users

the code is like so:

```
const mysql=require('mysql2');
const express=require('express');
let app=express();
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser.json());

let mysqlConnection=mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'db',
    password:'',
    port: "3306",
})

mysqlConnection.connect((err)=>{
    if(err)throw err;
    console.log('succeded');
})

app.listen(3001,()=>console.log('running'));


//get users
app.get('/users',(req,res)=>{
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM users',(err,rows,fields)=>{
        if(err)throw err;
        console.log(rows[0]);
        res.send(rows);
    })
})
```

It works pretty good with this address localhost:3000/users

But I cannot get results of the query to normal html address like: http://mysite/index.html

Thank you for any advise!

Comment: You need a server with a DNS address. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/deployment

Comment: Hello! Ty. I'm using open server. Which runs project on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

if want to use dynamic data like fetch from database then show the data to a webpage. Then you have to use template engines.
here is the ref: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html

Comment: if there is any query please let me know.
Thank You.

Comment: Ty for reply! If I toss a result of the query to pug, will I be able to toss pug render to html? Or is it too complicated? And I just need to change my html file to pug file?

Comment: Also can I send data to javascript file and from javascript render it to html. I'm trying to avoid pug or other template engines, because I have never worked with them and so I don't have too much knoweledge avout them.